# cardano node syncing stucked at some point

Tags: cardano-node

I am using cardano node version 1.35.3 but its syncing stopped at this point.

```
[otari457:cardano.node.ChainDB:Error:36] [2022-08-22 13:34:49.40 UTC] Invalid block 708745ea94515b679223a5514e6e6dba068208e5b79780134206f74e1e79e727 at slot 63419637: ExtValidationErrorLedger (HardForkLedgerErrorFromEra S (S (S (S (S (Z (WrapLedgerErr {unwrapLedgerErr = BBodyError (BlockTransitionError [ShelleyInAlonzoPredFail (LedgersFailure (LedgerFailure (UtxowFailure (MalformedScriptWitnesses (fromList [ScriptHash "eee7bfb25cfbbbcd31a1d5d648429ff919430ee5d06d8d056e48d605"])))))])})))))))
[otari457:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:36] [2022-08-22 13:34:49.40 UTC] Valid candidate ce9c9431882310df559099e2bfa3e6eb31c95606d83ffc05568df7f863d4db60 at slot 63419598
```

Comment: Have you tried stopping and restarting it?

Comment: yes.But it's not working. I am getting this when I run cardano-node --version, ```cardano-cli 1.35.3 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 950c4e222086fed5ca53564e642434ce9307b0b9``` It's latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You are running this node on the legacy testnet (network magic 1097911063), It's better to connect to one of the new testnet [(1)](https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html). You can for example connect to the pre-production testnet.

The block you described is only valid for node 1.35.2, other nodes will not accept. There was a bug.

Comment: Didn't get it what exactly need to do?

Comment: What tutorial did you use to launch the node?

Comment: Thank you @fermat . btw, the network magic set to 9

Answer (score 1):

I changed cardano-node to version 1.35.2, and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know and how it sounds is you are running on testnet. The latest supported version of cardano-node  that works is 1.35.2 for testnet. 1.35.3 will crash due to a bad block

Comment: This is not right. Actually the version 1.35.3 is working in Mainnet and it is ready for the hard fork in September 22.

Comment: @FalconStakepool we are talking about the testnet network. You are correct for preview, pre-prod and mainnet network 1.35.3 works fine.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that.